# How to say “no connection” or “connection is offline” in French?

Tags: informatique

Is any of these two correct in the context of an Internet connection?

> Pas de connexion
>   Connexion est déconnectée

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to say "pas de connexion" but not "connexion est déconnecté". it would be more appropriate to say "rupture de la connexion d'internet" for the second one.

Comment: Another option could be also "la connexion est restreinte."

Comment: Certainement pas « connexion d'Internet », en tout cas pas en France. On dirait « connexion à Internet » ou « connexion Internet ». Et l'expression « rupture de la connexion à Internet » est très lourde. @user3772

Comment: Si, "connexion d'internet" est souvent utilisée en France.

exemple :: https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/salaries-type-de-connexion-d-internet-nace-rev-1-1-dp/

Comment: I would use "connexion réseau".

Comment: Working in IT, I have never seen one of those propositions. If you have not benn connected so far, you will find `déconnecté` ou `hors ligne`. If you just lost your connection, you will find `perte de la connexion`

Answer (score 8):

*Pas de connexion* is correct. You could also say *Aucune connexion*.

For "Connection is offline", what optimal control said is right. You could also say *La connexion est inactive* or *La connexion n'est pas établie*, depending on context.

Answer (score 3):

«Débranché» is a word I have heard used often in this context. [This](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9brancher) cited usage refers more to electrical connections, but I see it used often in sysadmin circles to refer to internet connections. For example [here](https://www.debian-fr.org/reseau-connexion-fil-impossible-a-debrancher-t50382.html) as *débranchement* or, [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch-after-compromise.fr.html) as *débrancher*:

> Voir un rm -rf / s'exécuter au moment de débrancher le réseau du système n'est pas vraiment très drôle

Comment: It can be seen as a metaphor of the actual Internet cable being unplugged in this context (Débrancher means to unplug).

Comment: @PaulPicard That makes sense. I ended up doing some more Google searches for débranché and it did indeed seem mostly to be used in that figurative way.  I also found the literal expression *câble débranché*.

Answer (score 2):

ISO and IEC use *autonome*, *hors ligne*, *non connecté* or *en différé* depending on the context.

Comment: Je ne sais pas si on avait une référence particulière ici, ce serait intéressant; j'ai cherché des documents sur la terminologie sur le site _ISO_ mais je ne suis pas familier avec l'organisation des sujets, et c'est donc un peu compliqué... Merci!

Answer (score 0):

No connection→Pas de connexion.
Offline→Hors ligne.